# Como buscar por dos campos en una misma consulta php, mysql, jvscript. De la manera tradicional AND O OR no he podido

Tags: php

me sucede lo siguiente, al realizar esta consulta, solo me consulta por la serie, que esta declara en **$SWhere**, siendo que declare las dos variables para que me busque por serie o por identificacion. Es para consulta en una caja de busqueda div con jvscript. Sirve todo bien, pero busca o por serie o solamente por identificacion, y yo quiero que busque por cualquiera de los dos datos.

```
  <?php

require_once ("../conexion.php");

$action=(isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['query'], ENT_QUOTES)));

    $tables="express";
    $campos="id,serie,id_orden,identificacion,direccion,estado_rec,cable_hdmi,cable_av,fuente,control_1";
    $sWhere=" express.identificacion='$query'";
    $sWhere=" express.serie='$query'";

    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $acentos = $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = intval($_REQUEST['per_page']); //cuantos registros quieres mostrar
    $adjacents  = 4; //espacio entre páginas después del número de adyacentes
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Cuente el número total de filas en su tabla * /
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $tables where $sWhere");
    if ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)){$numrows = $row['numrows'];}
    else {echo mysqli_error($con);}
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    //consulta principal para recuperar los datos
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $campos FROM  $tables where $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page");
    //recorrer los datos recuperados

?>
```

Comment: Lo que falta es que sepas por cual campo estas buscando.. y eso aca no lo sabes. de alguna forma tu front debe decirle a tu back como buscar...

Comment: Estas sobre-escribiendo `$sWhere`, asígnalo sólo una vez: `$sWhere=" express.identificacion='$query' or express.serie='$query'";`

Comment: gracias, esta es la solucion!